# linq data context abstraction

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm finding myself writing this line for every query:

```
using ( MyDataModel thisDataContext = new MyDataModel() )
{
  linq query
}
```

Is there a better way to declare a data context?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a `DataService` class that represent your `DataContext`
e.g.:

```
 public  class BaseDataService:IDisposable
    {
       protected MyDataModel thisDataContext = null;
       public BaseDataService(string connection)
       {
           this.thisDataContext = new MyDataModel (connection);
       }


       public void Dispose()
       {
           this.thisDataContext.Connection.Close();
           this.thisDataContext.Dispose();
       }


    }
```

then create methods that satisfy your needs
e.g.:

```
public class YourEntityDataService:BaseDataService 
    {

        public YourEntityDataService(string connection):base(connection)
        {

        }

        public YourEntity GetYourEntity()
        {
//LINQ CODE
        }

        public void SaveYourEntity (YourEntity entityToSave)
        {
//LINQ CODE
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We actually put our data context object on the current thread as Thread Static object. Doing this does away with us having to pass the context object around to each method that needs it.

We have an n-tier architecture, and when our middle tier is called from a client, we just new up a context object and put it on the thread. Then, any method that needs to make a database call just pulls the context object off the thread. So, there are very few places in our middle-tier code where we are actually creating a context object. In fact, just one place, if I recall correctly.

Even with this method, our context objects don't live all that long (which is a good thing).